# Enabling a button when value is entered in input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

i have an input box(createBIAInput) that enables a save button(saveBtn) when a value has been entered into it. however it doesnt recognize when a value has been pasted into it with a mouse so save button(saveBtn) does get enabled. So i need to know how to enable the save button even when a value as been copied and pasted with a mouse.

FYI it works if you type in the value or you use "control V" to enter value.

Comment: Your question details are very vague. Could you please provide that piece of code, so we can not just guess, but actually provide an appropriate answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `onpaste` listener, that gets fired when you paste something into the `input`, like this:

```
var input = document.getElementById('createBIAInput'),
    button = document.getElementById('saveBtn');

input.addEventListener('paste', function(e) {
    button.disabled = false;
});
```

Or, using jQuery:

```
$('#createBIAInput').on('paste', function(e) {
    $('#saveBtn').prop("disabled", false);
});
```

So, **to enable your button when the users writes or pastes something**:

```
$('#createBIAInput').on('paste keyup', function(e) {
    $('#saveBtn').prop("disabled", false);
});
```

**Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/0cfvb9zc/1**

Comment: it worked with a minor adjustment. thanks:
// to enable save botton if value is pasted o
  $('.createBIAInput').on('paste', function(event) {
         $('#saveBtn').prop("disabled", false).removeClass('state-     btn-disabled');
             });

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#createBIAInput').bind('input propertychange', function() {
  $('#saveBtn').prop('disabled', false);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xkgme9vw/